# How to limit the amount of results when scraping

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, screen-scraping

Im trying to scrape a website and its working but I would like to limit the amount of results that come up. How would i do this?

```
req = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/list/ls026573448/')
soup2 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text,)

def pressed(self, instance):
    genre = self.genre.text
    if genre == 'Horror' or 'horror':
        soup2.select('h3')
        for x in soup2.select('h3'):
            print(x.text)
```

When i run this code about 50 results come up. How would i limit it to maybe 20 or 15?

Comment: Do you want to filter the results? If yes, what's the criteria for the filter?

Comment: no i dont want to filter anything @AndrejKesely I just want to get maybe the first 20 results instead of everything coming up

Comment: So when your results are in variable `results` (which is list) then e.g. for first 20 results you can do `results[:20]`

Comment: for i , tag in enumerate(soup2.select('h3')):
    if (i > 25):
        break
    else:
        print(tag.text)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using :has and :contains to isolate the appropriate elements then use `limit` to stop at 20 (thanks to @facelessuser for pointing that out). This is with bs4 4.7.1.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/list/ls026573448/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
films = [item.text for item in soup.select('.lister-item-header:has(~ p:has(.genre:contains("Horror"))) a', limit = 20)]
print(films)
```

Comment: Slicing is probably a waste of cycles. Instead, you should feed in `limit`: `soup.select('.lister-item-header:has(~ p:has(.genre:contains("Horror"))) a', limit=20)`. Doing this will cause the search to halt as soon as it hits the limit instead of filtering it after finding *all* the matches.

Comment: @facelessuser Marvellous. I didn't know about that. Thank you very much.

Comment: You pinged me?  I must have missed that as I didn't see any notifications in my inbox.

Comment: @QHarr hey i copy and pasted the films variable and applied it to my own code and its not working, i still get all the results coming up

Comment: Run my code exactly as shown above. You will get 20 results.

Comment: To debug problems with your integrating code I would need to see whole code that reproduces the problem. You can https://pastebin.com/ that if you want but first try running exactly as above.